# Adding a subcollection to mongodb python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, nosql

I am trying to add a sub-collections to my mongodb database, which is called FootballDB, within this db there are two collections; teams and matches.

I am trying to add to the teams collection, specifically I am trying to create a sub-collection within it called:

```
"players" : {"_id" : ObjectId(),
            "name" : "<name>",
            "number" : <num>,
            "position" : "<pos>"
}
```

This is how the teams collection currently looks:

```
{
  "clubs": [
    {
      "name": "Watford FC",
      "code": "WAT",
      "country": "England"
    },
    {
      "name": "AFC Bournemouth",
      "code": "BOU",
      "country": "England"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cardiff City FC",
      "code": "CAR",
      "country": "Wales"
    },
    {
      "name": "Huddersfield Town AFC",
      "code": "HUD",
      "country": "England"
    },
    {
      "name": "Burnley FC",
      "code": "BUR",
      "country": "England"
    },
... 
}
```

Currently, this is my code to add players to a sub-collection:

```
from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient
import random
import json
import names

client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
db = client.FootballDB
teams = db.teams

positions = [\
        'Goalkeeper',
        'Defender',
        'Midfielder',
        'Striker'
]
clubs = open('PLClub1819.json')
data = json.load(clubs)
for x in data['clubs']:
    for i in range(15):
        player = {
            "_id" : ObjectId(),
            "name" : names.get_full_name(gender='male'),
            "number" : random.randint(1,30),
            "position" : random.choice(positions)

        }
        teams.update_one({"_id" : x["_id"]}, {"$push": {"players" : player}})
```

However, I am getting the following error whenever I run it and try add it to the database:

```
  File "/XXXXX", line 28, in <module>
    teams.update_one({"_id" : x["_id"]}, {"$push": {"players" : player}})
KeyError: '_id'
```

I suspect it is due to each club not having an "_id" value, however I need more clarity so I am reaching out to the wider community

Help with these issues would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance all!

Comment: You have way too much going on in this question. Distil it down to one key issue per question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thats it shortened down to the main issue. Thanks for the input

Comment: Yes you will get that error if there is no "_id" value for any club

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me:
Dropping the collections with:
db.<collection_name>.drop()

and adding the following I was able to get "_id"'s for each club

```
def create_db():
    clubs = open('PLClub1819.json')
    data = json.load(clubs)

    for i in data['clubs']:
        teams.insert_one(i)

    matches = db.matches
    games = open('PLMatch1819.json')
    data2 = json.load(games)
    for i in data2['matches']:
        matches.insert_one(i)
```

And I also changed the following code to:

```
positions = [ \
        'Goalkeeper',
        'Defender',
        'Midfielder',
        'Striker'
    ]

for x in teams.find():
    for i in range(15):
        player = {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": names.get_full_name(gender='male'),
            "number": random.randint(1, 30),
            "position": random.choice(positions)

        }
        teams.update_one({"_id": x["_id"]}, {"$push": {"players": player}})
```